# adbコマンドでインストールされているアプリのバージョンを取得するには

Tags: android, adb

例えば`com.myapp`という名前のパッケージのアプリがAndroid端末にインストールされているとして、このアプリのバージョン番号(`versionCode`もしくは`versionName`)をadbコマンドで取得することはできますか？

Answer (score 2):

以下でどうでしょうか？

```
adi shell dumpsys package com.myapp
```

Answer (score 1):

```
adb shell dumpsys package packages
```

を実行すると各Packageの情報が表示されますので
その中のversionCode/versionnameを参照することで確認可能です。